# How do I insert text in the main body conditional on whether or not a label is defined

Tags: conditionals, labels

I have a set of documents I work with, where I include various files to complete them. So the main document might appear:

```
\section{Section A}

\input{SectionText1}

\input{SectionText2}

\section{Section B}

\input{SectionText3}
```

The reason I do this is so that I can change text in a single master file, and simply insert them into the different files I am trying to create. Therefore the important "SectionText" is the same across documents. I do not always include the same subfiles however, and I would like to put cross-references in, that will automatically be included in the main document if I have included the file with the label in it, but not print the relevant text if I have not.

To that end, I have created a new command:

```
\newcommand{\condlab}[2]{\ifdefined\r@#1 #2 \else \fi}
```

Which I execute in the text

```
\condlab{sec:Label}{The text I want to include}
```

That does not work. It always includes the text, *and* it includes the "@sec:Label"

If I write

```
\ifdefined\mycommand Include \else Not this \fi
```

In the text with a defined or undefined newcommand it works as intended. If I try:

```
\ifdefined\r@sec:Label
```

I get exactly the same result as with the newcommand, which makes sense. Suggestions?

Comment: Did you remember the required `\makeatletter\makeatother` pair that is required when dealing with macronames with @ in the name? Also you cannot do `\ifdefined\r@#1 #2 \else \fi` it will not make the macro ifdefined has to look at before it looks at it. You might want to have a look at the etoolbox package. Thirdly, please always post a full example instead of sniplet. Then it is a lot easier for others to test your code, they do not have to sit and guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing whether a macro exists is possible using

```
\ifcsname <csname>\endcsname
  % <true> (\<csname> exists)
\else
  % <false> (\<csname> does not exist)
\fi
```

This is simplified using [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\ifcsdef{<csname>}{<true>}{<false>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\condlab}[2]{\ifcsdef{r@#1}{#2}{}}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\label{sec:label}

\condlab{sec:label}{This text will be included.}

\condlab{sec:label2}{This text won't be included.}

\end{document}
```

The above usage (even with `\ifcsname <csname>\endcsname`) avoids the use of a [`\makeatletter`...`\makeatother`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764) pair since the control sequence is *constructed* rather than stated explicitly as a control sequence.